# How to aviod getting unsupported type(s) error when using sum

Tags: python, csv, sum

I'm new to python and I was trying to take data from a file, put it into a list and then get the sum of each line. I tried stripping the list for anything but int's and floats and made sure the file only had numbers. If anyone could help me I would be very greatful. Thanks for reading

(Problem code)

```py
with open("InputFileData.csv") as file:
    SampleTotalHours = file.readlines();

TotalHours = []

for element in SampleTotalHours:
     TotalHours.append(element.strip())

Sum = sum(TotalHours[0])
print(Sum)
```

(contents "InputFileData.csv")

```
40.1,39.7,40,38 
36,36,35.5,35.8
40,41.6,40.3,40
20.4,22.8,20,20
```

(Output)

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "D:\Assignment 6 Files\PAtest.py", line 10, in <module>
        Sum = sum(TotalHours[0])
    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Comment: The shown code only processes lines of the CSV-file as strings. It does neither split a line into separate entries nor converts it the entries to numbers.

Comment: Hint: add some `print` calls or use a debugger to see the values of `SampleTotalHours`, `TotalHours`, and `TotalHours[0]`.  You aren't doing whatever you think you are doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`readlines()` will return a list of strings, the first item in this case being "40.1,39.7,40,38".
To get the sum, you'll need to first split the string by the delimiter and cast each value to a float before taking their sum.

```
TotalHours = []

for element in SampleTotalHours:
    hoursAsStrings = element.split(',')
    hoursAsFloats = [float(hourString) for hourString in hoursAsStrings]
    TotalHours.append(sum(hoursAsFloats))
```

`TotalHours` is a list where each value is the sum of its corresponding row.

Comment: Thnaks so much this fix worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Kind of like this.  For each line, split it at the commas, convert the fields to floats, sum the floats.  You might find it easier using the `csv` module, but it doesn't really gain you much with this data set.

```
TotalHours = []
with open("InputFileData.csv") as file:
    for line in file:
        parts = [float(k) for k in line.strip().split(',')]
        TotalHours.append( sum(parts) )
print(TotalHours)
```

Answer (score 0):

This work for me fine:

```
TotalHours = 0

with open("InputFileData.csv") as file:
    for line in file:
        for number in line.strip().split(","):
            if number.replace('.', "").isnumeric():
                TotalHours += float(number)

print(TotalHours)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some popular libraries to look over (first built-in, the other 3rd party):

```py
import csv

with open('InputFileData.csv', newline='') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file,quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
    for row in reader:
        print(row,sum(row))
```

Output:

```
[40.1, 39.7, 40.0, 38.0] 157.8
[36.0, 36.0, 35.5, 35.8] 143.3
[40.0, 41.6, 40.3, 40.0] 161.89999999999998
[20.4, 22.8, 20.0, 20.0] 83.2
```

---

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('InputFileData.csv',header=None)
df['Sum'] = df.sum(axis=1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
      0     1     2     3    Sum
0  40.1  39.7  40.0  38.0  157.8
1  36.0  36.0  35.5  35.8  143.3
2  40.0  41.6  40.3  40.0  161.9
3  20.4  22.8  20.0  20.0   83.2
```